# Prestashop - no bootstrap in backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

### What is the problem

I recently gave theme support access to backoffice, but all they did is nothing and messing up my backoffice.

[image]

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.6.0 (and for some reasons I can't switch to newer version, so update is not an option). Everything was fine, but now I discovered that some backoffice pages (products, brands, attributes) are totally messed up. Looks like it lacks bootstrap, but I have no idea how to make it work.

As far as I know they were supposed to turn on SSL, but looks like domain still lacks certificate. Maybe because of turning it on, everything is messed up?

I have turned off cache and cache/smarty/ catalogs are clear, except index.php file.

### Things I did:

Console showed 4 errors. They were about missing fonts (404 error), included in theme.css (see below).

```
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,600,700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed);
@font-face {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(e79bfd88537def476913f3ed52f4f4b3.eot);
    src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"), url(570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe.woff2) format("woff2"), url(012cf6a10129e2275d79d6adac7f3b02.woff) format("woff"), url(a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2.ttf) format("truetype")
}

.material-icons {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

I found all included fonts in admin/themes/default/public and copied them to admin/themes/new-theme/public

Errors disappeared from console. It repaired icons, but problem still occurs:

[image]

### Where troubleshooting led me

theme.css on broken subpages is incorrect. Even if I don't have any cache and tried using private tab couple times - it does not match real file on FTP.

Here is screenshot of theme.css from sources tab on broken page:
[image]

And here is confirmation of same file with different content in FTP:

[image]

I don't have any caching on server - nothing!

Also when I copy correct theme.css content into wrong one in sources page (which is supposed to be correct, because it's same file!) - subpage is 100% working in a flash. Unfortunately only local.

I even tried to attach this file via direct URL, as you can see in screenshot below - it didn't helped. (Highlighted line is original link rel, which leads me to good path file, but still with wrong content).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After founding out that theme.css is different (still curious how it changed itself) and trying to replace it - I finally tried to remove it from FTP. After that I again cleared all cache, visited broken site without any CSS and then uploaded new one.

Maybe it was about some update or other stuff. However I copied theme.css from theme/default/public and placed it in theme/new-theme/public.

Now subpages are working correctly.

Comment: I know it's kinda weird but sometimes if PHP version is not compatible some UI elements like <select> doesn't render well. maybe, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the cache after turning it on the SSL? — it can also cause the problem.

At first glance, it looks that have bootstrap loaded, but some other CSS is not loaded correctly.

If you look at the console window(F12), you can see the resources the page could not load. That might help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I updated question according to your idea with sources. I think it's definitely about boostrap as you can see now.

Comment: If there is bootstrap on a page, it should be on every page.. in general. 
Have you tried it in another browser or in an incongation window?

And could you check please the console window? Because if the browser can't load a file because it's missing, you'll see it there.

Comment: Well, you were right about sources tab. I though that I arleady checked that. It points missing file and surely - that file does not exist both on working and broken installation. You can check screenshots in updated question.